# When do physical reads indicate a lack of RAM?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, memory, query-store

With Query Store, I can track how big my physical reads are and how often they occur. How can I tell if these numbers are so big that they indicate that I need more RAM?

For that it's worth, my other research indicates that I don't have a RAM issue:

- My waits are 99% SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER
- Page Life Expectancy varies a lot throughout the day, but I've never seen it below 200.
- The oldest queries in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` are about a month old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For monitoring waits, there are certain benign waits you can usually ignore.  A quick lookup on [SQLSkills](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/sos_work_dispatcher/) suggests that `SOS_WORK_DISPATCHER` can probably be ignored so I would look at the next wait type.

[This is the query](https://github.com/trimble-oss/dba-dash/blob/main/DBADash/SQL/SQLWaits.sql) DBA Dash uses (a monitoring tool I created) for capturing waits if you want a list of exclusions you can use. I'm not 100% sure of the original source of this list of exclusions - possibly SQLSkills, which is my usual go-to place for information on wait types.

If the next wait is a `PAGEIOLATCH*` wait that might be an indication that more memory might be beneficial.

PLE doesn't tend to be that reliable of a metric.  I'd also look at monitoring disk IO to see how much data you are reading from disk.  I tend to use the information from [sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-io-virtual-file-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for this.  Perfmon counters could also be used. Also, look at disk latency as an indication of how your disks are performing.

The more memory you have the less you should need to read from disk and queries will perform faster.  More memory will almost always be beneficial but if `PAGEIOLATCH*` isn't a significant wait type on your server it might not have the desired impact.

---

Query store is great for a lot of things, but I wouldn't use it for this purpose.  At least not as a starting point.  I'd start at a higher level - wait stats and server/database/drive level IO stats.  If you determine your server is bottlenecked by IO query store could be used to determine which queries you might want to look at tuning.  You might find some easy wins there that reduce your IO.  If not, more memory might be a solution.

Query store works at the database level and even then, it might not track your whole workload. `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` or perfmon counters will be more accurate in tracking your IO at a higher level and wait stats will give you a good idea if IO is a significant bottleneck. But if you have determined that you have an IO bottleneck, query store might be able to help identify which queries are contributing to that.